# Show alert on textbox on invalid input

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I know that I can restrict textbox to pass only numeric with this:

```
<input type="number" id="box_1">
```

But alert is showing only after clicking submit button. How can I show it in `on-key` event with JavaScript?

Comment: What alert are you talking about?

Comment: Alert like this: http://john.foliot.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/input-required.jpg

Comment: There is no way (that I know of) to show the error tooltips without clicking a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Go with Jquery. something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="numbersOnly" value="" />
```

And:

```
jQuery('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, although I know I can replace the signs - but can I force textbox with my JavaScript to show this http://john.foliot.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/input-required.jpg on keyup event?

Comment: Have you added Jquery lib ?

Comment: Ok then Go with Jquery validation plugin. http://formvalidator.net/#configuration_html5

Comment: I was hoping that I can implement this with no external sources. Seems to be pretty basic thing. Although, it's still the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this : it detects if the user has entered letters

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var txtbox_1 = $('#box_1');

        // Setup the event
        txtbox_1.focusout(function () {
            var last = $.data(txtbox_1, "last");
            if ($(this).val().match(/[a-z]/i))
                alert("Letters");
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="box_1" name="box_1" type="number">
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey I think You want something like this.

Check it [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/vqekwxp2/)

Comment: Put the answer in your post, not a fiddle.